# Is there a formally-defined converse of a Prominence Walk?

Tags: geophysics, geography, terminology, topography

My question was inspired by [this one](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/3018) - in particular, the subtopic of pumping water from the ocean to the below-sea-level basins to deal with rising sea levels (spoiler: it's horribly infeasible and impractical).

I have also read about topographic prominence, [line parent(s)](http://www.peakbagger.com/help/glossary.aspx#lineparent), [key cols](https://bivouac.com//DfnPg.asp?DfnId=1033), and the concept of a "[prominence walk](https://bivouac.com//DfnPg.asp?DfnId=1052)".

Then, I was reminded of my experience futzing around with Google Earth's elevation data when trying to understand how [Lake Assal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lake_Assal_(Djibouti)) is the lowest point in Africa (-155 meters / -510 feet) yet it's unusually close to the ocean (only about 5 km from the Gulf of Aden).<sup>1</sup>

Obviously there's a saddle point above sea level which separates this lake and ocean, plus there are line parents and a prominence walk crossing this saddle point,

but,

how about the line of *lowest elevation* leading up to this saddle point from each of the Lake and the Gulf, i.e. the *converse* of a prominence walk?

**In terms of physical geography and the study of prominences, is there a formal name for this line?**

<sup>1</sup> Somewhat related:  I've been intrigued for decades about how Reno, Nevada is 4500' elevation but nearby Lake Tahoe is 6220'.

Comment: In mathematics, the "line of steepest descent".